# Force exerted by atmospheric pressure as compared to gas pressure in a piston

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

[image]

In the above problem, the force exerted by atmospheric pressure on the piston is the product of the atmospheric pressure and the exposed piston area, which is the area of the piston less that of the shaft. While I can see why that is the total atmospheric force exerted on the piston it is not clear why that is the total atmospheric force, because the shaft is also exposed and the atmospheric force should also act on the shaft. So the total atmospheric force would equal the atmospheric pressure times the piston's area. Can someone explain why because the shaft is present the atmospheric force is the product of the atmospheric pressure and the piston's area less that of the shaft?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the specified gas pressure *gauge* or *absolute*?

Comment: The pressure is absolute

Answer (score 1):

They are asking for the force on the shaft. Apparently that is to include the contribution from the atmosphere.

Comment: But that means the atmospheric force does act on the shaft. According to the textbook, the atmospheric force only acts on the net area at the top of the piston, the piston's area less the shaft's area.

Comment: I edited the question to include the solution

Answer (score 0):

Write the equality of opposite forces acting on the piston.

$m_{p}\times g+m_{sh}\times g+p_{atm}\times S_{p} +F=p\times S$

Comment: According to the textbook, the atmospheric force only acts on the net area at the top of the piston, the piston's area less the shaft's area

Comment: the piston's area less the shaft's area: compare them. shaft's area irrelevant.